# Live Color picker for text using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, fonts, colors

I have gone though one of the beautiful color pickers farbtastic and able to get the color and now I need to change the font color immediately as we pick the color from it.

So how do I do that?I knew it's a stupid question but I need to know!

This is what I got from the site:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="farbtastic.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="farbtastic.css" type="text/css" />
```

Placeholder:

```
<form><input type="text" id="color" name="color" value="#123456" /></form>
<div id="colorpicker"></div>
```

Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#colorpicker').farbtastic('#color');
  });
</script>
```

This is my textbox:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" BackColor="Transparent" BorderStyle="None"
                autocomplete="off" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score -1):

try giving the textbox a class, like .colored-textbox

and instead of

```
$('#colorpicker').farbtastic('#color');
```

try

```
$('#colorpicker').farbtastic('.colored-textbox');
```

Comment: If I change it dosen't pick's up any color.

Comment: can you give the html of the textbox?

Comment: <input type="text" id="color" name="color" value="#123456"/>

Comment: Ok so can you give the textbox the class="colored-textbox" ?

Comment: Yes if I give as you said and change it to what you have mentioned above it's just showing me the control but nothing is selecting.

Comment: It seems that I am a bit sleepy, sorry. I missed the part with the font color. So leave everything as it was, but change the script to:
 `code`$('#colorpicker').farbtastic(function(color){$("#color").css("color", color);});

Comment: You should look at Demo2.html that comes with farbtastic. it will show you how to connect the picker to a class even when there are multiple instances. You just need to convert the input elements to ASP.NET textbox and set the CssClass property accordingly. it also shows how to use a callback. Where you can plugin the code to change the CSS color attribute as needed.